# tabular side-by-side

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, positioning

I am trying to get two tabular constructs side-by-side with a tikz figure in between and can't seem to get what I want using the minipage construct. Here is the code I have

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz-rdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.callouts,,decorations.text,shapes.misc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes.geometric,backgrounds,fit,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}[b]{.30\textwidth}
  \centering
  \scalebox{.6}{
      \begin{tabular}{| p{1.5cm} | c | c | c |} \hline
        title & nationality & locatedIn & salary \\ 
        ?t & ?n & ?p & ?s \\ \hline
        Professor  &  American & USA &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
        Professor  &  American & China &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
        Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$45,000 \\ \hline
        Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$45,000 \\ \hline
        Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$45,000 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
  }
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[
                     -triangle 90,
                        line width=1mm,
                        postaction={draw, line width=0.3cm, shorten >=0.3cm, -}
                ] (0,0) -- (1,0);
           \end{tikzpicture}


\end{minipage}
        %
 \begin{minipage}[b]{.30\textwidth}%{80mm}
        \centering
                 \scalebox{.6}{
              \begin{tabular}{| p{1.5cm} | c | c | c |} \hline
                title & nationality & locatedIn & salary \\ 
                ?t & ?n & ?p & ?s \\ \hline
                Professor  &  American & USA &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
                Professor  &  American & China &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
                Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$135,000 \\ \hline
              \end{tabular}
            }
        \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
          \captionof{table}{Current and Mean B with a Reversed Polarity}

        \end{document}
```

The output I am getting is the following. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Where would one obtain `tikz-rdf`?

Comment: @Werner: it's not needed.  Nor `tkz-graph` nor `tkz-berge`, which were also not in my distro.

Comment: i'd start by inserting `\leavevmode` before the first `minipage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,column 1/.style={nodes={text width=1.5cm}}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
            draw,
            %outer sep=2mm,
            %
            ] (firsttable) {
        title & nationality & locatedIn & salary \\ 
        ?t & ?n & ?p & ?s \\ \hline
        Professor  &  American & USA &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
        Professor  &  American & China &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
        Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$45,000 \\ \hline
        Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$45,000 \\ \hline
        Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$45,000 \\ 
};

\matrix[matrix of nodes,
            draw,
            right = 2 cm of firsttable.south east,
                        anchor= south west,
            ] (secondtable) {
                title & nationality & locatedIn & salary \\ 
                ?t & ?n & ?p & ?s \\ \hline
                Professor  &  American & USA &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
                Professor  &  American & China &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
                Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$135,000 \\
};
 \draw[
                     -triangle 90,
                        line width=1mm,
                        postaction={draw, line width=0.3cm, shorten >=0.3cm, -}
                ] ([xshift=3mm]firsttable.east |- secondtable.west) -- ([xshift=-3mm]secondtable.west);

\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
\draw (firsttable.north west -| firsttable-1-\x.north east) |- (firsttable.south west -| firsttable-4-\x.north east);
}
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
\draw (secondtable.north west -| secondtable-1-\x.north east) |- (secondtable.south west -| secondtable-4-\x.north east);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Current and Mean B with a Reversed Polarity}
\label{tikztable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*EDIT*:  I've repositioned the table and drawn verticle seperators. However it is strongly recommended to avoid vertical seperators but that's a whole another story and I am not literate enough to comment on that.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution, never thought of that. Could you please also tell me how to align the tables at the bottom with this solution? Also, I assume you cannot get vertical separators for the columns?

Answer (score 4):

You are using twocolumn so `\linewidth` is rather less than half `\textwidth` but your table widths add up to more than that, don't you want to base the widths on `\linewidth`? or `\columnwidth`, probably better.

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks. One more question -- how do I get the bottom of the two tables aligned? I thought putting [b] after minipage should do that, but it doesn't seem to be accomplishing what I wanted.

Comment: you need a [b] on the \begin{tabular} so the table aligns on its bottom row (also don't forget to upvote&accept if it works:-)

Comment: Thank you. FOr some reason, it also pushes the arrow down (i.e., it aligns the tikz figure at the bottom as well).

Comment: well yes if latex aligns three things in a row it does so so their baselines line up, by default the baselines of the table are in the center. If you [b] align the tables you will need to raise the arrow, I don't know tikz at all it may have an alignment option or you could put the tikzpicture into a `\raisebox{5\baselineskip}{....}` or some other length and raise it by whatever you need

Answer (score 3):

It you wrap them all in one `minipage` they get placed next to each other. Also you should be using `figure*` in a `twocolumn` document:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      ...
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

I added `\usepackage{showframe}` so that you can see where the margins are and adjust your settings as desired:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{tikz-rdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.callouts,,decorations.text,shapes.misc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes.geometric,backgrounds,fit,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.30\textwidth}
  \centering
  \scalebox{.6}{
      \begin{tabular}{| p{1.5cm} | c | c | c |} \hline
        title & nationality & locatedIn & salary \\ 
        ?t & ?n & ?p & ?s \\ \hline
        Professor  &  American & USA &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
        Professor  &  American & China &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
        Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$45,000 \\ \hline
        Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$45,000 \\ \hline
        Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$45,000 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
  }
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[
                     -triangle 90,
                        line width=1mm,
                        postaction={draw, line width=0.3cm, shorten >=0.3cm, -}
                ] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.30\textwidth}%{80mm}
        \centering
        \scalebox{.6}{
              \begin{tabular}{| p{1.5cm} | c | c | c |} \hline
                title & nationality & locatedIn & salary \\ 
                ?t & ?n & ?p & ?s \\ \hline
                Professor  &  American & USA &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
                Professor  &  American & China &  \$100,000 \\ \hline
                Assistant Professor  &  Canadian & China &  \$135,000 \\ \hline
              \end{tabular}
        }
\end{minipage}
\captionof{table}{Current and Mean B with a Reversed Polarity}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a `%` after your `\end{minipage}` commands:

```
...
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
...
```

[image]

Comment: @user8801: You are welcome. One point: Here at stackexchange we thank [user] by upvoting [his/her] answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote). Additionally, please finally accept the answer that helped you most (by clicking on the checkmark).