# Place side by side two tables

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I have two tables side by side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side)

I would place two tables side by side in the same row. How can I do? what packages I should use? does is exist a simple way to make it? May you help me?

Comment: yes I know it but there are only for images?

Comment: No. Just use environment `table` instead of `figure`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46523/tabular-side-by-side

Comment: You will most likely find a solution if you search for [`[floats] side by side`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfloats%5D+side+by+side). For example, [Two figures side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5769/5764) would translate to tables as well.

Comment: You can put each in a `minipage` slightly less than half the `textwidth`. If you wish you can then put the two minipages in a `figure` so they float.

Comment: I've added another answer to [How can I have two tables side by side?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2832) ; let us know if your question is a duplicate, or else please let us know what is different :)