# Strategy for listings next to code comments

Tags: listings, minipage, tabularx

I'm looking for strategies to produce listings of code with comments on what's happening next to it. I've found other similar questions, but not quite what I'm looking for. See for example:

- [Listing side by side example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125106/listings-and-sidecap-side-captions-for-listings)
- [Another side by side example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46523/tabular-side-by-side)

However, what I'm really looking to do is reproduce a result similar to the notes in my Finite Elements text by Thompson shown below:

[image]

Things that come to mind are creating minipages, or using a tabular format. I know brute force could be employed here, but I reckon there is a more elegant solution. Any pointers on where I can look would be greatly appreciated as my searches are all coming up with "almost there" results.

Comment: There are other solutions listed [here](http://ctan.org/topic/parallel).  I can think of problems if you want to adjust the listing-lines with those on the right hand (e.g., the last 2 lines right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `minipage` environment coupled with the `mdframed` package. Of course, there's also the `listings` package for the code.

This example answer is tweaked for margins of `1.5cm` on each. If you increase the margin (reducing the available space for the content) you should also fix the `\textwidth`s of the minipages.

Since the minipage on the right is not verbatim, you'll need to manually add space between the text blocks so they match the other side. There are examples of how to do it in the code below.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings,mdframed}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,breaklines=true}

\begin{document}\footnotesize%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}%
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=none]  % Start your code-block

% ----------------------
% BOUNDARY CONDITIONS
% ----------------------
 B = 1.0E+06;
 for I=1:NUMNP
  if NPBC(I) == 1 | NPBC(I) == 3
   I1 = 2*I-1;
   SK(I1,1)=SK(I1,1)*B;
   RHS(I1)=LHS(I1)*SK(I1,1); 
  end
  if NPBC(I) == 2 | NPBC(I) == 3
   I2=2*I;
   SK(I2,1)=SK(I2,1)*B;
   RHS(I2)=LHS(I2)*SK(I2,1),
  end
 end

% ----------------------
% CALL EQUATION SOLVER
% ---------------------- 
 LHS = sGAUSS(SK,RHS,NUMEQ,IB);

% --------------------------
% Nodal values for w and dw/dx are now
% in LSH. Use this values to calculate
% shear and moment at center of element.
%
% First calculate shape functions
% and their derivatives. Ic is
% counter for number elements used
% --------------------------
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{1mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{mdframed}
\vspace{2mm}
Specify boundary conditions.\\

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    NPBC & $w$ & $dw/dx$ & $V$ & $M$ \\ \midrule
    0 & U & U & K & K \\
    1 & K & U & U & K \\
    2 & U & K & K & U \\
    3 & K & K & U & U \\    
\end{tabular}
\\[5mm]
where\\
K = known\\
U = unknown
\\[2cm]
Call equation solver for symmetric, banded storage.
\\[1cm]
Begin calculations of shear and bending moments at center of each element.
\end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\null
\end{document}
```