# How to create LaTeX example codes using verbatim and large braces?

Tags: tables, diagrams, verbatim, arrays

I read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/side-by-side-source-and-output-when-documenting-a-style-file) it's useful but isn't exactly what I need.

My problem consists in create an array, table or something like that with two columns. In the left one I need to put LaTeX code with `\verb` or `verbatim`, but in the right instead of the result, I need to and braces for explain each part of the another column.

My MNWE:

```
    \documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-handout}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
    \usepackage{array{
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{lc}
    \verb+
    \documentclass[options]{class}
    + & \\
    \verb+
    \usepackage[options]{package}
    + & \left. \right\} preamble \\
    $\vdots$ & \\
    \verb+
    \begin{document}
    + & \\
    $\vdots% & \left. \right\} body \\
    \verb+
    \end{document}
    + & \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do. Is simple a kind of diagram about the basic LaTeX structure, but I don't know how to build it.

Comment: Would [something like this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245577/4778) do it for you?

Comment: @Aradnix: You need `\verb`? Or isn't `listings` allowed?

Comment: I would recommend you use `listings` for the LaTeX` code and `\tikzmark` to mark the appropriate points in the LaTeX code, and then use `tikz` to do the drawing of the braces and the annotations.  This way you can separate the code from the annotation and have more flexibility and readability of the original code.

Comment: @Alenanno interesting, but is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer can be `listings` also, but `\verb` is a simpler option. In fact my problem isn't with the code but with the other column, where I need, in this case, add an indication with braces.

Comment: @Aradnix: Yes, I see -- I am not sure this is possible with `listings` in a easy way. I think Zarko's answer is quite good.

Comment: @PeterGrill It's a good idea, perhaps the best choice except that I don't know how use (yet) TikZ well and I have no idea how to do what you say. Otherwise maybe your suggestion is complemented with Christian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in your WME. I only correct them and use `article` and instead of `tufte-handout` (I havent instaled it in my MikTeX). Also I comment the `babel` for the same reason:

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb+\documentclass[options]{class}+ &     \\
\verb+\usepackage[options]{package}+  & $\bigg\}$   preamble \\
$\vdots$                              & \\
\verb+\begin{document}+               & \\
$\vdots$                              & $\bigg\}$   body \\
\verb+\end{document}+                 & 
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
From comment of OP follows, that curly braces should spanned more rows: This can be achieved on various way, I will limit myself to use of `multirow`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb+\documentclass[options]{class}+   &   \\
\verb+\usepackage[options]{package}+    &   
    \multirow{2}{*}{$\bigg\}$ preamble}\\
$\vdots$                                &   \\
\verb+\begin{document}+                 &
    \multirow{3}{*}{$\left.\rule{0em}{5.5ex}\right\}$ body}\\
$\vdots$                                &   \\
\verb+\end{document}+                   &   \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I know about the errors, that's the reason why I called MNWE (Minimal NOT Working Example) because it was an sketch about my idea. Now my doubt with your solution is how to enlarge the braces to fit exactly with the preamble and body sizes in the other column. I mean, how to fit them since `\documentclass` line until the vertical dots in the first case?

Comment: About sizes of your braces: do you like that they span for example `begin{document} ... \end{document}? If this is case, two solution cross my mind: use `multirow` package and enlarge `}` or draw it with tikz in `overlay` option.

Comment: I see from all the previous comments that I have to find out how to get it with TikZ.

Comment: Hm, seems to be with `multirow beter solution,. See, eddit of my answer

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I need for now. Thanks for the helping. However I think it is urgent to learn well TikZ to do these things better soon.